# React router V4 link to external address

Tags: react-router-v4

I've tried a few different recommendations, however, none seem to work. I'm using react router V4 and I would like to create a link that navigates to an external website. Currently, everything I do just appends to my URL.

**What I want to happen**
www.mysite.com => click internal link and go to => www.newsite.com

**What is happening**
www.mysite.com => click internal link and go to new page but it appends => `www.mysite.com/www.newsite.com`

`<Link to="http://www.newsite.com">Go to new site</Link>`

Comment: Why do you have to use Link? If you want external redirects, go for plain < /a> tag.

Comment: Jeepers. Can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks

Comment: No worries!, We all have been there!

Comment: @Giri add your comment and code as answer so that this question can get marked as answered. bp123 don't overuse React components if you can do it easier with simple html ones and using simpler operations ;)

Comment: @Giri, I didn't realise that I was supposed to post the solution you recommended. I didn't want to take credit for it. Thanks agin.

Comment: Sorry, missed the notifications. And regarding "credit", I really don't care about credits here. I'm happy, that I was helpful to you to figure out what was wrong and that's enough!. Have a great day and happy hacking!

Comment: There's a very good reason to want this. For a discussion, see https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution to this was what @Giri suggested, a simple HTML link.

```
<a href="http://www.newsite.com">New site</a>
```

Comment: I am having the same problem using an a tag.

Comment: @Mel If anyone else has this problem you have to use `<a target="_blank" href="http://www.newsite.com">New site</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your own component as suggested [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1147#issuecomment-113180884):

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

const Anchor = (props) => {
  return props.href ?
    <a {...props}/>
    :
    <Link {...props}/>
};

export default Anchor
```